# Get list of user's friends which contain other app post in their feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

After reading all facebook docs and google search i am posting this question because i unable to find the answer.

- Application A - my application
- Application B - Someone else    application

I want to test user's friends who's feed contain post by Application B. I just need true or false without fetching their posts. because fetching feeds of every friend is slow and wrong way. is their any way to get list of friends in true or false way. Please suggest any single Graph API or FQL to get list.

thank you. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no straight “true/false” query for that.

You could just filter the contents of the [FQL `stream` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) by `app_id` for each friend, and use `LIMIT 1` to break the search off when the first post made through that app for that user is found.

And of course you could make that a multi-query, to fetch the data for all friends at once, to limit the number of necessary HTTP requests.

Comment: can you post an example how batch query goes.

Comment: Multi-queries are explained right on the start page of the FQL docs.

Comment: thanks but there should be a way to get only true or false it will be lot more easy and consumes less bandwidth and time.

Comment: Well, you can try and get that transmitted as a “Feature Request” of some sort to the FB developer team … but since the kind of data you want is not a very common use case, I doubt that they’ll consider implementing something like this …